# Use `Connect-AzAccount` multiple times without prompt

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using `Connect-AzAccount` in some automation scripts and it is really frustrating that every time the cmdlet is called I'm asked to authenticate, even though I authenticated very recently. Is there a way to make the cmdlet search for existing context and re-use it when possible? I don't want to use cert or app authentication, just reuse the existing context on my machine (without having to do so explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows PowerShell and run `Connect-AzAccount` and are prompted to provide credentials in a window that pops up, you can run the below command  to use device code flow to authenticate.

`Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication`

Providing this additional parameter will notify the user of the code they must use in https://microsoft.com/devicelogin to authenticate.

Comment: This doesn't help. I still get prompted for credentials.